# ios 7 Push Notification didReceiveRemoteNotification method run on UI thread or separate thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

`(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler` method run on UI Thread or separate background thread? Because I need to process data based on push message and store in local database table using Core Data. If I do Core Data operations in this method,it will disturb the UI or not?

Comment: Just thought I'd add a comment that his is easy to test with a breakpoint.  Set a breakpoint in the method and send trigger a notification to see what thread it executes on.

Answer (score 0):

every application delegate method run on main thread only. try to avoid doing big task over there. if its small task it wont disturb the ui.

Comment: I need to split a string and store it as array and then store the array values to database using core data.How to do this in separate thread?

Comment: i am not familiar with core data but u use Magical Record to store the data. also there is no need of separate method for that.

Answer (score 0):

[application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application) is part of [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit), which is tied to the UI thread:

> Use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread or main dispatch queue, unless otherwise indicated. This restriction particularly applies to classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.

UIKit follows its own rules by calling this method from the UI thread. This makes it easy to use other UIKey methods, but you are responsible for ensuring that your method returns quickly.

Answer (score -2):

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
               didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
                    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

method run on separate background thread because when we are using our application than notification received by application. So its means this method run on separate background thread.