# didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler background thread or main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety, silent-notification

I am working on core data and silent notifications. I don't have any thread safe implementation in core data. And when i get silent notifications i need to fetch & save couple of items into database.

So my question is does didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler always works on main thread? (Even the app is on background).

I did the experimentation, i sent silent notification when app is on the background, didReceiveRemoteNotification triggered in Thread 1(UIThread).

But still i want to make sure and prevent crashes related with thread issues.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)
{

}
```

Comment: you can check using . . . 

if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
            NSLog(@"Main Thread");
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Not on Main Thread");

Comment: Duplicate of [didReceiveRemoteNotification method run on UI thread or separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20896993/145173).